# Gamma distribution - closed towards multiplication

Tags: probability, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

First observe how the gamma distribution function can be written in terms of the incomplete gamma function.

$\boldsymbol{(1)} \qquad G(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \dfrac{c^{\gamma}}{\Gamma(\gamma)} x^{\gamma - 1}e^{-cx}dx = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\gamma)}\int_{0}^{cy} z^{\gamma- 1}e^{-z}dz = \mathfrak{S}(\gamma,cy )$

$Y \sim \Gamma(\gamma,c)$

Now, in my book the statement is: "From this we see that the family of gamma distributions is closed towards multiplication with a positive constant, that is, for $\rho > 0 $ we have  $\rho Y \sim \Gamma(\gamma,c/\rho)$"

My question is: How can i see from (1) that the gamma distribution has this property (closed toward multiplication)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly:  let $W = \rho Y$ where $Y$ is distributed as described.  Then $$\Pr[W \le w] = \Pr[\rho Y \le w] = \Pr[Y \le w/\rho] = G(w/\rho).$$  Then we have $$G(w/\rho) = \mathfrak{S}(\gamma,cw/\rho) = \mathfrak{S}(\gamma,(c/\rho)w).$$  Thus $W \sim \Gamma(\gamma,c/\rho)$.  All of this is just a fancy way of showing that $c$ is a scale parameter of the gamma distribution; that is to say, if $Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\gamma,c)$, then $\rho Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\gamma,c/\rho)$, if using the rate parametrization for the gamma distribution.